# Function names ending with ()

Tags: javascript

How does JavaScript deal with functions with names ending with `()`? Consider for example the following piece of code:

```
var foo() = function () { }; // The empty function

var bar = function(foo) { var myVariable = foo(); };
```

It seems like there are two possible interpretations for what `foo();` means:

1. Execute the argument `foo`. This assigns `myVariable` the returned value of `foo`.
2. Consider `foo()` as the name of the function defined at first. This assigns `myVariable` the empty function.

Is this even legal code? If so, what are the rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this even legal code?

No:

```
var foo() = function () { };
```

should be:

```
var foo = function () { };
```

> If so, what are the rules?

In this case the `foo` argument will have precedence because it is defined in an inner scope than the `foo` function. So it's really a matter of scope: where is the variable defined. The interpreter first starts by looking in the innermost scope of the code, then in the outer, ... until it reaches the global scope (the window object).

So for example the result of the following code will be `123` as seen in this [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3UeG4/):

```
var foo = function () { alert('we are in the foo function'); };
var bar = function(foo) { var myVariable = foo(); alert(myVariable); };
bar(function() { return 123; });
```

Answer (score 2):

The `()` isn't considered part of the name. You'll probably get a syntax error. You can find some naming rules [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Variables).

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, brackets mean execute.  So your code will fail as it will be looking for a function foo on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers may not contain any parentheses, so the first statement is illegal. The second, however, is fine, `myVariable = foo()` executes the `foo` parameter and assigns the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really mean "Can I pass functions as references?" If so, then the answer is yes:

```
var foo = function() { return 2; }
var bar = function(fn){ return fn(); }

var two = bar(foo);
```

Comment: try using chrome's javascript console, or firebug